# How to communicate multiple meaning in a sentence more concisely?

Tags: style, creative-writing, technical-writing, technique, word-choice

Good day everyone,

I have the following sentence:

> Around 70% of small businesses in the United States struggle to hire
>   qualified employees, and around 50% attribute this challenge to
>   candidates' lack of skillset needed for the job. This is our area of
>   focus.

My issues are as follow:

- The word around is repeated twice, and hence feels redundant
- I am not sure if people feel that "this is our area of focus" ties directly to candidate lack of skill set of the general problem which is hiring qualified employees.

  - I am not sure if they clearly understand what "this challenge" refers to.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am mainly targeting hiring managers looking for developers in small businesses.

Comment: You'll also want to clarify whether it's 50% of small businesses or 50% of the 70%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work.

> Approximately 70% of small businesses in the United States struggle to
>   hire qualified employees.  Almost 50% of those
>   small businesses cite lack of skills of potential employees as the
>   reason jobs go unfilled.  Filling those jobs with appropriately
>   trained candidates is our focus.